# testing angular with protractor .net wrapper

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I test angular app with protractor wrapper for C# (something like this https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net)

When I switching to frame with recaptcha, NgWebDriver waits captcha reset.
But I need to return to the parent frame and submit the login form.

```
public void CompleteCaptcha()
{
    WebAssert.IsDisplayed(LoginPage.CaptchaElement.Frame);

    var mainFrame = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
    Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(LoginPage.CaptchaElement.Frame);

    WebAssert.IsDisplayed(LoginPage.CaptchaElement.Checkbox);

    Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("document.getElementsByClassName('recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark')[0].click()");

    Driver.SwitchTo()
        .Window(mainFrame);

    LoginPage = new LoginPage(Driver);
}
```

I've found the problem- its in WaitForAngular function. I can't skip wait for recaptcha's scripts

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it using protractor.

```
browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);

//some code...

browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I'm not familiar with `protractor-net` but I imagine it's probably similar.

Try `Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();`